# Angular 8 "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: angular, tabs

I have a problem when I want to return the length of an array in Angular, The message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" appears in the console.

```
  count: number = this.organismesFinanceurs.length;
  organismesFinanceurs: OrganismeFinanceur[];
  config: any = {
    itemsPerPage: 7,
    currentPage: 1,
    totalItems: this.count,
  };

ngOnInit() {
   this.serviceHttp2.getAllOrganismes().subscribe(resp => (this.organismesFinanceurs = resp));
}
```

And the Array OrganismeFinanceur[] is as following:

```
[
{
  "code": "ASS. NAT.",
  "libelleCourt": "FSS ASSEMBLEE NATIONALE",
  "libelleLong": "FONDS DE SECURITE SOCIALE DE L ASSEMBLEE NATIONALE ET DU PERSONNEL"
},
{
  "code": "AUTRE REG.",
  "libelleCourt": "AUTRE REGIME SPECIAL",
  "libelleLong": "AUTRE REGIME SPECIAL"
},
{
  "code": "BANQ.DE FR",
  "libelleCourt": "BANQUE DE FRANCE",
  "libelleLong": "BANQUE DE FRANCE"
},]
```

Comment: does it solved your issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `organismesFinanceurs: OrganismeFinanceur[] = [];`